# Prevent default response code in Swagger/OpenAPI definition with NestJS

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

### What I'm trying

I'm implementing a DELETE route using NestJS.

Since the route is only ever supposed to return a `HTTP 204 No Content` on successful deletion, utilizing the `@nestjs/swagger` decorators, I've annotated it as follows:

```js
@ApiParam({
  name: 'id',
  required: true,
  type: 'string',
  example: 'abc123',
})
@ApiNoContentResponse({
  description: 'All items for the given id have been deleted',
})
@Delete('/accounts/:id/items')
async deleteItems(
  @Param('id') id: string,
) {
  // do stuff
}
```

### Stack

```
@nestjs/cli: 9.1.6
@nestjs/common: 9.1.6
@nestjs/core: 9.1.6
@nestjs/platform-express: 9.1.6
@nestjs/swagger: 6.1.2
```

### nest-cli.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      "@nestjs/swagger/plugin"
    ]
  }
}
```

### Question

How can I prevent this (default?) response from being generated?

### What happens

When running the server with `npm run start:dev`, the swagger description for my route is created. Although I've not explicitly defined it, the description now contains an entry for `HTTP 200` in the `Response` section of the route. The entry contains no description and no indicator that it's not explicitly defined.

### What I expected to happen

When running the server with `npm run start:dev`, the swagger description for my route is created. The description only contains and entry for `HTTP 204` in the `Response` section of the route.

### What I've tried

Explicitly defined an `@ApiOkResponse`:

```js
// they all have no effect
@ApiOkResponse()
// OR
@ApiOkResponse({})
// OR
@ApiOkResponse({ status: 204 })
```

Defined an `@ApiDefaultResponse`:

```js
// they all create a response 'default' with no description
@ApiDefaultResponse() 
// OR
@ApiDefaultResponse({})
// OR
@ApiDefaultResponse({ status: 204 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `@HttpCode(204)` as an annotation to your code. 200 is added by default, because this is the default response status code for `DELETE` requests.This default behavior would be overwritten with the annotation mentioned above.

More information about the status codes can be found here: https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers